# How to pass a class object to initialization in Python

Tags: python, self

I have an outside function that builds up a class from an array, and if I want to initialize the class with an array using the same function, I tried the equivalent of the following code:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self,x):
        if type(x) == int:
            self.val = x
            self.next = None
        elif type(x) == list:
            self = build(x)
    def __str__(self):
        node = self
        test_str = ''
        while(node):
            test_str += str(node.val)
            node = node.next
        return test_str

def build(array: list) -> Test:
    root = Test(array.pop(0))
    cur = root
    while array:
        cur.next = Test(array.pop(0))
        cur = cur.next
    return root

b = build([1,2,3])
print(b)

b = Test([1,2,3])
print(b)
```

The first print is 123 which is fine, the second gives an error, 'Test' object has no attribute 'val'. I looked everywhere else and can't figure out how to do this. Why can't I do this, and what is the correct way to achieve what I wanted (except for copy and modify the build function into **init**)?

Comment: `self = build(x)` doesn't do anything useful. It just changes the value of the local name `self`, without modifying the instance of `Test` passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

It has no attribute `val` because you initialized your class with a list. The attribute `val` is only created when pass an integer when initializing.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a separate class method for one of the two cases, rather than sniffing the type of the argument. It makes *your* code simpler, and it makes code *using* your code simpler.

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, x: int, next: 'Test' = None):
        self.val = x
        self.next = next

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, lst: List[int]):
        if not lst:
            raise ValueError("Cannot create empty Test")

        root = Test(lst.pop(0))
        cur = root
        while array:
            cur.next = cls(lst.pop(0))
            cur = cur.next
        return root

    def __str__(self):
        node = self
        test_str = []
        while(node):
            test_str.append(str(node.val))
            node = node.next
        return ''.join(test_str)
```

Then

```
b = Test.from_list([1,2,3])
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on why the code using this class would be simpler? Because I think it is simpler to call Test([1,2,3]) than to call Test.from_list? Do you know a way to get the same result by just Test([1,2,3]) without completely rewriting the build function? Because in the real case that function was much more complicated.

Comment: Because you are making it clear *to the caller* that `Test` is instantiated differently based on the argument type. All I've really done is renamed `build` to `from_list` and forced you to call it explicitly, rather than having `__init__` magically guess whether to call `build` or not.